# How to put data validation in a column for duplicate values in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have to put data validation in column "B" for duplicate text values.
so users cannot enter duplicate values in column "B".

I used the custom formula for this and it is working fine but it has a limitation.
when user copy and paste values then it is not working, it is only working when user enter values by typing into a cell.

My custom formula:
`=COUNTIF($B$10:$B$1048576,B10)=1`

I am expecting a solution that even user cannot enter duplicate values by copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [Worksheet.Change event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) to your worksheet and test for duplicates there. If a duplicate was inserted (pasted or typed) then just `.Undo` the paste.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("B"))

    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then  'if at least one cell in column B was changed
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In AffectedRange 'loop throuh all changed cells in column B
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Me.Columns("B"), Cell.Value) > 1 Then 'test if it is a duplicate
                Application.Undo 'undo the paste/insert
                MsgBox "Duplicates are not allowed", vbExclamation
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Peh I am trying some enhancement in this code. like if my cell has text value like "is StackOverflow is a good website ?" so, in this, I just want to check for text value and leave "?". ex: if in another row in the same column has a text "is StackOverflow is a good website", the code also works in this scenario too.

Comment: @SandeepBhatt If this is a question please ask a new one. We can only answer one question at a time.